# How to copy complex formula across?

Tags: excel

1. I have the formula =SUM (indirect(C5:C"&ROW()-1))

How do I copy this across so if changes automatically to be "D5:D"

I was usIng basic SUM formula but need to add rows and data too much for tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using INDIRECT, since it's a volatile function.  Try the following instead...

```
=SUM(C$5:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1))
```

Comment: Excellent. Works great

Comment: Also just worked out same for colums with minimal fuss - learning every day ; ace